# "Upload" function in input form which creates a folder on local network and stores pdfs in it for CRUD app on local Network based on PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, networking, directory, crud

I have a big problem and hope someone can help me here.

I am making a CRUD App to store data about Students on it. I am at the end of the work but still have one really big problem and I have find nearly nothing in the internet.

In one create page I must be able to choose students from other tables insert the name of the project that he is working on and "upload" pdfs related to this student. ""upload"" because we are planning to use this CRUD App on local University network.

The idea is, when people created a new "studentsworks"  and click on "upload files" they can choose pdfs from a folder on local folder. After clicking the submit button, PHP must take this file - besides of inserting the text information into mysql - and create a folder on a specific path, give automatically a name to this folder, insert this file(s) into this folder and safe the path to this folder in the mysql database to make it possible for the/another admin/user to open this folder in the faculty network with a click on a button in the details/update page of this "studentsworks" to update the files or to open this pdfs to check for more information.

Is something like this possible? I hope I described my problem accurately.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like this is certainly possible. These are the basic functions that can be found in many, many, *many* digital management systems.

Let's go through these requirements one at a time:

**On one page I must be able to:**

1. choose a student
2. insert the name of the project they are working on
3. upload PDFs (or any file, really)

Selecting a student can be done with a dropdown list but, if this is for a university, there could be *thousands* of people. A dropdown list would be inefficient as heck. Perhaps an `<input>` that takes a student ID would make more sense? A little bit of JavaScript could be used to return the name of the student to show on the page and act as a confirmation.

Inserting the name of the project would be another `<input>`.

Uploading PDFs (or any file) the old-school way can be done with an `<input type="file">` within a `<form>` that uses a `POST` to send data. For example:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="student-id">Student ID:</label>
        <input type="text" id="student-id" name="student-id" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="project-name">Project Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="project-name" name="project-name" value="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="file">Choose File(s) to Upload:</label>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="image/*,.pdf" multiple>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

On the PHP side, you will need to look for the existence of an array in the `$_FILES` global variable. Uploaded files are stored in a temporary directory when uploaded, which will allow you enough time to:

1. determine where the file should be stored
2. do any pre-processing before saving the file

When you know where the file should be saved, you can do something like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[0]['tmp_name'], '/path/to/save/data');
```

Make sure your web server has permission to write to that location, of course.

This can seem a little overwhelming at first, but there is a lot that you can do with online systems once you know how to work with these concepts.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a little bit for more research.